# Определение строки по маске node.js

Tags: node.js

Доброго времени суток!

Возникла необходимость определять соответствует строка маске или нет. Вариантов масок достаточно много и перебирать каждую строку через indexOf не очень удобно, да и думаю не совсем правильно.

Вообщем приведу несколько примеров масок:

```
эта строка https://example.com/post338159850
должна соответствовать
этой маске https://example.com/post[тут данные]
```

В предыдущем варианте сложности нет, а вот в следующем не очень уже удобно

```
https://example.com/post338159850?z=add_user5676465_546776845783%2F4767HJG8hjg76897fgn
https://example.com/post[тут данные]?z=add_user[тут данные]_[тут данные]%2F[тут данные]
```

чтобы определить эту строку мне надо проверить с помощью indexOf `https://example.com/post` и `?z=add_user` и `%2F` и если все вернуло 1 то говорить окей это эта строка и начинать юзать сплит до потери пульта пока не получу все параметры и не помещу их в переменные.

Есть ли способ который кучу этого бесполезного кода превратить в проверку на маску через тот же if или лучше всего switch - case и разделит строку на массив `['338159850','5676465','546776845783','4767HJG8hjg76897fgn']`

Если есть подобные готовые варианты то будет очень круто а если нет я так понимаю прийдется написать свою функцию

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вообщем немного изменил маску и использую regexr... вообщем вот готовые функции которые мне нужны были:

```js
/*
возвращает false или true в зависимости от результата

compares(
'https://example.com/post338159850?z=add_user5676465_546776845783%2F4767HJG8hjg76897fgn',
\https:\/\/example.com\/post[0-9]*\?z=add_user[-?0-9]*_[0-9]*%2F[A-Za-z0-9]*\);

*/
function compares(str, mask) {
    try {
        if ((str.length == 0 || str.length == undefined) && (mask.length == 0 || mask.length == undefined)) {
            return false;
        }
        let res = str.match(mask);
        if (res != null) {
            if (res[0] == str) {
                return true;
            }
            else { return false; }
        }
        else { return false; }
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}

/*

достаем любые данные с любого текста используя маску [data]

parse(
'https://example.com/post338159850?z=add_user5676465_546776845783%2F4767HJG8hjg76897fgn',
https://example.com/post[data]?z=add_user[data]_[data]%2F[data], [data], (err, res) => {
        if (!err) {
            let from_id = res[0];
            let owner_id = res[1];
            let party_id = res[2];
            let hash = res[3];
        }
    }); 

*/

async function parse(match, mask, char = "[data]", callback) {
    try {
        if ((match.length == 0 || match.length == undefined) && (mask.length == 0 || mask.length == undefined) && (char.length == 0 || char.length == undefined)) {
            return callback(new Error('Incorrect data was transmitted.'));
        }
        let string = mask.split('[data]');
        string.pop();

        let result = [];

        for (const [index, value] of string.entries()) {
            result.push(match.replace(value, '').split(string[index + 1])[0]);
            match = match.replace(value, '').replace(result[index], '');
        }

        return callback(null, result);
    } catch {
        return callback(new Error('Parsing failed.'))
    }
}
```